# If a positive integer m was increased by 20%, decreased by 25%, and then increased by 60%, the resulting number would be what percent of m?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

> If a positive integer $m$ was increased by $20$%, decreased by $25$%, and then increased by $60$%, the resulting number would be what percent of $m$?

A common step-by-step calculation will take time.

After $20$% increase, $6m/5$.
After $25$% decrease, $9m/10$.
After $60$% increase, $144m/100$.
Finally, $m \cdot \frac{x}{100} = \frac{144m}{100} = 144$%

what is the faster (or, fastest) method to solve this?

Comment: Noting that this is a GRE question, I'm not surprised. They give you lots of questions that tempt you to do algebra when doing algebra is the slow, mistake-prone way to do them. Whenever possible on that test, do arithmetic instead of algebra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to do this is to dispense with algebra, and instead of calling your original amount $m$, call it $100$.

A $20\%$ increase turns $100$ into $120$.

A $25\%$ decrease takes off $1/4$ of that, leaving $90$.

A $60\%$ increase adds $6/10$ of $90$, which is $6\times 9$, which is $54$. Thus, $90+54=144$.

Since you started with $100$ and ended with $144$, that's a $44\%$ increase.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would put into my calculator:
$$
1.2 \times \underbrace{0.75}_{=1-0.25} \times 1.6 = 1.44
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac 65*\frac 34* \frac85=\frac{144}{100}$$

Comment: The usage of fractions was my idea as well. You even don´t need a calculator since  it can be cancelled.

Comment: not really $6*3*8=18*8=36*4=72*2=144$. Easy to do mentally

Comment: That was I meant. And additionally it can be cancelled.

Answer (score 0):

There is no shorter method. Only thing you can do to make it short is do all calculations in the end. Log would've worked but it is for only even increases/decreases and for a long period of time
OR
For an alternative take the number as 1, it doesn't change anything except making expression simpler.